# Does SELECT query lock a table or a page in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, locking

We have just upgraded our production sql instance from 2012 to 2016 Standard Edition. As we have been working hard to find deadlocks in case it exists, i have just faced one and didnt quite understand what is exactly happening. The reason i did not understand the issue is that one session is blocking another session but the blocking session is a select query session. it prevents another session to insert the table.

The blocked session query is;

```
INSERT INTO [AUDITHISTORYLOG_BACKUP_2017_1]([TABLE_NAME],[OPERATION_TYPE],[HOST_NAME],[USER_NAME],[PRIMARY_KEY],[FIELD],[OLD_VALUE],[NEW_VALUE],[CREATE_DATE]) values(@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8,@9)
```

The blocking session query is;

```
SELECT * FROM AuditDB.dbo.AUDITHISTORYLOG_BACKUP_2017_1 WHERE CREATE_DATE>CAST(GETDATE()-30 AS DATE) ORDER BY CREATE_DATE DESC
```

How does this select query block the insert transaction ?

Wait_Type: LCK_M_IX
Wait_Resource: PAGE: 10:1:20598647
Transaction Isolation Level: Read Committed

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How does this select query block the insert transaction ?

Yes it can cause the types of locks are not compatible. A `SELECT` query requires `SHARED` lock whereas `INSERT` requires `EXCLUSIVE` lock and both are not compatible. That is, a shared lock if present on the same resource (in your case `AUDITHISTORYLOG_BACKUP_2017_1` table) on which exclusive lock is requested; that exclusive lock can't be granted until the shared lock is taken off or shared lock have been released.

Comment: I did not know that exclusive locks requires shared locks to be released. And also, i have never faced this type of issue before this upgrade. That is why im digging into the cause of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.

Comment: @Rahul yeah, i did it